# Execute .exe file which contains 2017 number in name via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I try to copy newest file from network folder and execute it. In location where I need to copy 2017 file I have 2015 file, but I need to execute only 2017 file.

```
# Copyfile from network shared folder to folder in host machine

Get-ChildItem "\\r\Pro\Al\Ort\Daily B\2017\x64" -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
New-Object psobject -Property @{
    No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
    Name = $_.FullName
}

 } | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\User Name\Desktop" 


# Execute .exe file

Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\User Name\Desktop" -Include *exe*, *2017* | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
New-Object psobject -Property @{
No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
Name = $_.FullName
}

} | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | 
Foreach { & $_ -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=server -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes"}
```

When I execute this script nothing happens.

Comment: Likely one of your cmdlets is not returning anything so you later cmdlets in the pipeline are not executing. Can you confirm the file exists? Also, `-include` and `-exclude` work better with `-recurse`. I think a filter would be better here. `Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\User Name\Desktop" -Filter  "*2017*.exe"`. Can you confirm the files exist where you expect them to be? I think we need some more debugging from you to help. The code otherwise _appears_ OK.

Comment: Matt, yes I see file and it exists. After I changed `-include` to `-filter` and used `"*2017*.exe"` instead of `"*exe*, *2017*"` - it works perfectly! If you don't mind, make an answer from your reply and I'll vote for it as an answer!

Comment: No need. If that is your issue then the dupe covers the issue. Glad it is working for you.

Comment: Thanks again, Matt. And for future - if I want to count some text values and numbers should I use such syntax `"*2017*, *CL*, .exe"`?

Comment: If your filter starts getting complicated you can post process with `Where-Object` like you are with your examples above. That filter has no wildcards so you would only return the file named that exactly.

Comment: Matt, thanks again!